# Why is the map activity terminated in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, mapactivity

I can't figure out why it's terminated. Errors and code shown below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do not post links to images of your error.  Post the text directly here.

Comment: Hi welcome to SO . Please read [ask] .

Comment: it's likely a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put some configurations in your manifest:

```
<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
```

In the **application** entity of you xml file.